Is it possible to reset charge state of my laptop's battery?
My laptop's battery has been drained (according to its counter). But it's actually impossible to drain the power at all (I made some external electrical connections).
I want to reset the battery's charge counter, so that my consequent problems (immediate wake-up from suspend) will be over, I guess.
How can I do that?

This can't be done from the operating system.  Typically you reset it by fully draining it and then fully charging it.  If this doesn't work, bet battery is at end of life.

Can't it be overridden by the operating system as if it reports some custom charge state?

Even if this was possible, it would not be safe.  Overcharging a lithium battery will make it explode.  Of course, OS software is free to report to the user whatever numbers you want, but that has nothing to do with the information in the battery monitoring chip.

It sounds like you are saying that you wired an external power source to the battery connectors.  If this is so, the problem probably lies in the fact that there are probably additional connections used (I think) for monitoring purposes, that probably aren't connected.  One thing you might try is rebuilding the kernel without battery monitoring features (which I'm not sure you can do, but I would expect to be possible).

Not sure how removing power management from the kernel would help without making the problem worse, but you can disable it without recompiling the kernel anyway.

modprobe -r battery didn't work.
